# Mastering Ethereum Book - Rot13Encryption.sol - Line 22 incomprehensible

Tags: evm, mastering-ethereum

What does this mean?
I know that ADD evm opcode is to add the top two items in the stack together, but i can't get the following code.

```
add(add(text,0x20), mul(i,1))
```

[image]